# How to prevent colab Resources tab from showing?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm using google colab pro, and irritatingly, the Resources tab keeps showing itself after I've closed it.  It doesn't appear to be showing me anything new, and it is not in response to any action.  It just randomly pops up every few minutes no matter how often I've closed it.  I can collapse the divider down so that it is small, and it stays, but that is a work-around.  Why does it keep popping up, and is there a way to prevent it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out.  It looks like it was the Colab Alive chrome extension trying to do its job.  I removed the extension, and that fixed my problem.